# GWT: Margin by Anchor

Tags: css, gwt, anchor, margin

I have a anchor-object in my gwt-application.

There i set an text and the following css.

```
.notification{
font-family: Lucida Sans;
font-size: 25px;
height: 60px;
background: url(images/notification-bar.png) no-repeat top left;
}
```

I want to set the height to 60px, but currently it is always as height as the text is.

---

with display: block; it works fine...

I inserted text-align:center; to get the text (not the background) in the middle.
Now I want to get  the text also in the vertical center.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`height` CSS property does not apply and has no effect on *inline* elements like `<a>`. You can add `display: block;` to your style, but obviously it depends on your circumstances if this is the right solution.

Comment: with display: block; it works fine...

I inserted text-align:center; to get the text (not the background) in the middle.
Now I want to get  the text also in the vertical center.

How do I do that?

Comment: The easiest method to vertically center text is to just add line-height: 60px; to your style.